# XMLstarlet copy element's content between elements

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet, yq

I need with `xmlstarlet` or `yq` to copy the content of an element into an other element, placing to the start or the end of it.

Using this kind of xml:

```xml
<products>
  <product>
    <id>01</id>
    <Title><![CDATA[ Product 1 Title ]]></Title>
    <Dimensions><![CDATA[ S ]]></Dimensions>
    <Size><![CDATA[ for Adult ]]></Size>
  </product>
  <product>
    <id>02</id>
    <Title><![CDATA[ Product 2 Title ]]></Title>
    <Dimensions><![CDATA[ Medium ]]></Dimensions>
    <Size><![CDATA[ for Kids ]]></Size>
  </product>
</products>
```

i try to copy the content of each Dimensions and Size elements into the start or end of Title element, using this bash:

```bash
xmlstarlet ed -u /products/product/Title -x "concat(/products/product/Title,' ',/products/product/Dimensions/text(),' ',/products/product/Size)" sourcefile.xml > outputfile.xml
```

but the problem is that the Title of first product element is copied in every other product element. I expect:

```xml
<Title><![CDATA[ Product 1 Title S for Adult]]></Title>
<Title><![CDATA[ Product 2 Title Medium for Kids]]></Title>
```

but i receive:

```xml
<Title><![CDATA[ Product 1 Title S for Adult]]></Title>
<Title><![CDATA[ Product 1 Title S for Adult]]></Title>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of `yq` do you mean?

##### Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

`yq` provides the options `-p` and `-o` to set the input and output format; both take the parameter `xml` or `x`.

```bash
yq -o xml -p xml '
  .products.product[] |= (.Title += " " + .Dimensions + " " + .Size)
' sourcefile.xml > outputfile.xml
```

##### Using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

To manipulate XML files, `yq` provides `xq`, which converts the XML file into JSON, then uses [stedolan/jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) for manipulation. The `-x` option converts the output back to XML:

```bash
xq -x '
  .products.product[] |= (.Title += " " + .Dimensions + " " + .Size)
' sourcefile.xml > outputfile.xml
```

##### Output

For both, the `outputfile.xml` should then look like:

```xml
<products>
  <product>
    <id>01</id>
    <Title>Product 1 Title S for Adult</Title>
    <Dimensions>S</Dimensions>
    <Size>for Adult</Size>
  </product>
  <product>
    <id>02</id>
    <Title>Product 2 Title Medium for Kids</Title>
    <Dimensions>Medium</Dimensions>
    <Size>for Kids</Size>
  </product>
</products>
```

##### Using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)

Here you can go with:

```bash
xmlstarlet ed -u /products/product/Title -x '
  concat(../Title, ../Dimensions, ../Size)
' sourcefile.xml > outputfile.xml
```

Then, the `outputfile.xml` would then look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <id>01</id>
    <Title> Product 1 Title  S  for Adult </Title>
    <Dimensions><![CDATA[ S ]]></Dimensions>
    <Size><![CDATA[ for Adult ]]></Size>
  </product>
  <product>
    <id>02</id>
    <Title> Product 2 Title  Medium  for Kids </Title>
    <Dimensions><![CDATA[ Medium ]]></Dimensions>
    <Size><![CDATA[ for Kids ]]></Size>
  </product>
</products>
```

---

Note: The important thing (for all three approaches) is to traverse to each `product`, and collect the items for concatenation from their children only. With both `yq` implementations, this is achieved using the update operator `|=`. For `xmlstarlet` you need to move with relative XPaths using `..` to go up one level.

Also note, that there are formatting/encoding differences between these tools. Use them according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much. Tested xmlstarlet and works great. I just added " ", for spacing. I will test later on yq and comment again